# Flex ActionScript - ArrayList Issues

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, actionscript

I am banging my head for the last couple days in order to get this done but Im unable to. Someone please help me out!
Let me not tell u the whole thing and will try to explain it simply n clearly. 
Im having 1 ArrayList. I am trying to replicate that into another one and trying to delete an item at a particular index. But this not only deletes the item in the replicated ArrayList but also the original ArrayList.

For ex:

```
var DuplicateList:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
DuplicateList = OriginalList;

DuplicateList.removeItemAt(2);
```

The above not only deletes the "Item 3" at Index-2 in the DuplicateList but also in the OriginalList.

I just need some workaround with this approach as this is the only way by which whatever I typed inside the controls present in an ItemRenderer of a FLEX List control that uses the OriginalList as a dataProvider is RETAINED, when I change the dataProvider of the List Control from OriginalList to DuplicateList. The following approach does not retain all the data.

```
var DuplicateList:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
DuplicateList.addAll(OriginalList);

DuplicateList.removeItemAt(2);
ListCntrl.dataProvider = DuplicateList;
```

Thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 2):

A very, very important thing to understand:

ActionScript3 uses references to objects.  Because of that, the two variables in this line of code refer to the exact same instance of an `ArrayList`:

```
DuplicateList = OriginalList;
```

So, when you remove an item from one reference, it is gone from the next.  If you want two separate instances of `ArrayList`, then you need to clone it like you are suggesting later in your code.

So far, so good... but why is your `ListCntrl` retaining the data from the `OriginalList`?  That doesn't make any sense at all.  If you remove an item from `DuplicateList` and then use it as the data provider, then that item shouldn't be there.  I think there is more to this story...